# Trying to understand the use of loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am going through the documentation on the page https://angular.io/api/router/Routes and there I found a keyword "loadChildren".

I am finding it hard to understand it.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you familiar with the concept of [NgModule lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular we have a lazy loading concept

**In General:** we will import and declare the component in the root module(i.e app.module.ts) and we will set the path in root routing file like mentioned below

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: AboutComponent},];
```

here the all the components loaded in the app module will be downloaded in the browser on the initial load it self which affects the performance and initial loading time

**Lazy Loading:** we will just load children the sub modules in the routing files so on request of the path only it will load the components present in the module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    loadChildren: "../app/about/about.module#AboutModule"
  },
  {
    path: "service",
    loadChildren: "../app/service/service.module#ServiceModule"
  }
];
```

In above code will download the about component only if the user loads the path **about** in the browser.